# How to handle C# large MSMQ data calls to SQL stored procedures efficiently?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have been searching extensively for solutions or alternatives to the following approach to handle large data processing:

We are currently using a C# Windows service (call it Listener) to listen to TCP ports and save incoming messages to the MSMQ (Message Queue) to make sure that no data is lost. At the same time, we have another C# Windows service (call it Decoder) that reads from the MSMQ, processes the data in multiple threads and calls SQL stored procedures to save the data and do additional data processing.

The rate of incoming messages is around 10,000 message/second and each message is processed individually by the Decoder and then send to the SQL SP, but recently we are facing some issues related to the performance and high Server resources usage (CPU and RAM).

We are currently investigating using SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS) as an alternative to read the messages from the message queue and do the processing and execute the stored procedures but it seems like it has some limitation when it comes to the Message queues.

Now my question is, what do you think are better alternatives to the current system design given that we have to use SQL Server to store data?

Comment: SSIS, in my opinion is like buying one of those all-in-one hi-fi systems.  Sure it does everything, but they generally don't do anything particularly well.  Too bad if one part is really bad or you wish to upgrade it. That's why purists prefer to buy the best _receiver_; the best _amp_; the best _blu-ray player_ that all integrate into a cohesive whole.  SSIS is SQL Server trying to be both a _message routing and orchestration system_ when perhaps you're better off using a specialist system like _BizTalk_ or at least keep communications out of the database layer.

Comment: Is your high resource consumption on the sql server or on the machine running the "decoder"?  Or, are the one in the same?

Comment: The high resource consumption is on the SQL server.

Comment: the sql server may be getting pounded because of all of the individual operations.  Could the "decoder" process a batch of messages and send to the db as a single operation?  Is it just inserting data?  If so, what about bulk inserts (using SqlBulkCopy)?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is intended for ETL-type workloads -- think batch processing files and synchronizing data across systems (especially rdbs).

Processing lots of messages which need a bit of massaging, Kafka (https://kafka.apache.org/) and hadoop might do better there.  Even if at the end of the process it pushes data to SQL server or you pull it in via ssis.

m